# Why do the other nodes modify if they are not given by reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

I dont understand why is 10 added.
"Node" is passed by value in "Insert" so it s ok that the root modifies but why do its children?
When the insert(left child of root) is called why does it modify, it is passed by value, not by reference?

```
class Node
{
public:
    int key;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

Node* insert(Node* node, int key)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return(newNode(key));
    node->left = insert(node->left, key);
    return node;
}



int main(){
    Node* root = NULL;
    root = insert(root, 20);
    root = insert(root, 10);
}
```

Comment: It isn't quite clear what modifies what. What output are you getting from this program? What output do you expect?

Comment: You don't pass the nodes by value, you pass *pointers* to the node (by value). By calling the `insert` function you create a copy of the pointer to the objects, so you have two pointers pointing to the same object. You can use either pointer to modify the object. That's why the assignment `node->left = ...` works in the function.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: You pass a pointer to a Node class instance to `insert`, neither a value nor a reference.

Comment: First time it's null, and new `Node` with value 20 as it's `key` is created. Next time you pass a `root` those was created previously, it's not null, so a recursive call to insert is performed with arguments Node->left, that is null at this point, and 10 as key. The result is assigned to `left` member value. So after all you have a root with 20 as key value and a Node with 10 as key, assigned to the root's `left`